# load YAML in Java

Tags: java, java-8, yaml, java-stream

I am trying to read a YAML file in Java using the following code:

```
public class LoadFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {             
      Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
      InputStream inputStream = LoadFile.class
       .getClassLoader()
       .getResourceAsStream("ABSOLUTE PATH TO YAML");
      Object obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
      System.out.println(obj);    
  }
  }
```

But I get this exception which I don't understand why it occurs.

> Exception in thread "main" org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Does the getResourceAsStream returns a stream or null?

Comment: Your path is almost certainly wrong, leading to `getResourceAsStream` returning `null`.

Comment: Is this really your complete code? I've seen this happen when loading multiple YAML documents with `loadAll` and not processing the results until after the input stream is closed. That can happen when the `loadAll` is in a try-with-resources block and the results are used outside the block. It could perhaps happen with `load`, too, although in a simple test with a small YAML file, it didn't.

Comment: Also, what version of snakeyaml are you using? I was using 1.26 in my test.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious what causes the problem but there is some stuff to check:
1- make sure that the path is correct
2- make sure that the file format is correct

side note: 
you can change Object to be a  `Map<String,Object>`  for better casting

Comment: You don't know whether the YAML file is loadable into a `Map<String, Object>`.