# Getting value for a variable using external file in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can i get the value "TestValue" from `application.properties` file in springboot project. The `messageVarible` in not static final.

```
@Component
public class testMapper {
   public String TestMessage() {
        String message-variable = "TestValue";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `TestMessage` as a bean and Autowire it. I am guessing that you did not read about java in general since you happen to be missing the general concepts of naming a method. Please do read about java before jumping onto spring boot.

Comment: This is just a sample code so didnt follow the naming conventions. However is there any method to inject values into a local variable. @Value cannot work with local variables

Comment: The below solution will not work for local variables

Comment: It can be done with vanilla Java itself. It will depend on the use case. Please create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the property to application.properties or any other properties resource file loadable by spring boot. then you can read it inside your application like that

```
@Value("${messageVariable}")
private String messageVariable;
```

where you defined in your file like that

```
messageVariable=any message
```

or if you are using yaml file

```
   messageVariable:any message
```

Comment: Although `messageVariable` would work, stick to the standards `message-variable`

Comment: Yes that true but message-variable is a local variable and @Value will not work over that

Comment: For Spring Boot, when providing` `messageVariable` and `message-variable` are the same.

Comment: If you want it locally, I think you should do it yourself

Comment: Yes there are lot of string local variables. and. i wanted to read them. from a file

Comment: take a look in this answer on how to load yml files inside a method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031850/load-yaml-in-java/62032370#62032370